# How do I call p5.Vector.fromAngle() in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, p5.js

I have imported P5 into a Vue app as follows:

```
let script = p5 => {
  p5.setup = _ => {
    this.setup(p5)
  }
  p5.draw = _ => {
    this.draw(p5)
  }
}
this.ps = new P5(script)
```

Everything works fine when I try to access methods like `background(0)` (`p5.background(0)`) but if I try `p5.Vector.fromAngle(angle)` I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromAngle' of undefined
```

I believe this is a static method but I need help on how to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540987/p5-vector-subraction-sub-returning-error) answer.
Use `p5.constructor.Vector.fromAngle()`