# p5 vector subraction 'sub' returning error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js

I'm have been trying to upload a p5 sketch onto a react build. Using react-p5-wrapper I am able to successfully render my canvas on the screen however, some vector functions are causing errors.

```
        var distance = this.position.dist(ball.position)
        var minDistance = this.radius + ball.radius
        if (ball === this || distance > minDistance) {
            return
        }
        // balls colliding. First, move them apart.
        console.log(this.position) 
        console.log(ball.position)
        let angle = p5.Vector.sub(this.position, ball.position)// <= RIGHT HERE[![Error Message][1]][1]
        // return
```

In this portion my console.logs both return valid 3D vectors however when I use the p5.Vector.sub(v1, v2) I am returned an error that says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sub' of undefined". I the sub function perhaps being confused with something else? I have included a picture of my error output. Im not sure why the program is reading them as undefined when I get values for them in console.log. Thank you for any advice

Comment: The error is telling you that `p5.Vector` is nothing, so calling `p5.Vector.whatever()` can't ever succeed. Not that your arguments are bad. So: check if `p5` actually exists in scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the author of `react-p5-wrapper` here in [this issue](https://github.com/and-who/react-p5-wrapper/issues/42)

> the p5 that gets passed into the module isn't the same as the global p5 you traditionally get with a script tag. To access certain things with this package (due to the p5 node module itself) you need to use p5.constructor.[something]

Basically use `p5.constructor.Vector.sub(this.position, ball.position)` in your case.

Comment: You are correct that was exactly the problem! Adding p5.constructor completely removed the error. Thank You